# What is the proper way to update all elements of a rendered page via AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, comet, long-polling

I have a complicated page being rendered by PHP and would like to keep all elements of the page up to date via AJAX long polling.  Is there some kind of general / clever way to design an infrastructure to support this without having to specify manually each element to update?  Just looking for ideas.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery, I would send a comma-separated list of jQuery selectors to update to the server. The server will ultimately respond by reading those selectors and producing the HTML to fill up the elements matching the selectors:

```
$.get("/updater", { elementsToUpdate: "#someDiv,#someTable,#someOtherElement"}, function(json) {
      $.each(json, function(k, v) {

        // the key is the selector, the value is the 
        // HTML to set to that (or those) element(s):
        $(k).html(v);
      });    
}, "json"); // we are expecting the server to return JSON
```

The server will respond by sending JSON to the client with the following structure:

```
 {"#someDiv":"this is some HTML to fill up div with ID someDiv","#someOtherElement":"here is some more HTML","#someTable":"here is some more HTML"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can poll a page which returns you the json-encoded structure of your page, like:

```
var page = {
    'elem1': {
        'html': '<div>... ',
        'update': True
    },
    'elen2': {
        'update': False
```

and so on, then update what necessary, having only one poll.

Comment: Hi -- thanks for the answer.  I'm not sure what you mean by "pool a page?"  Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe add a special class to all the elements to be updated via ajax, and also you can encode extra data in some other attributes for example

```
<a class="ajaxUpdate" data="{'a':'json or whatever', 'put whatever here':'ok'}">test</a>
```

then with jquery you can easily pull out that data and eval it, and use it in your ajax

Answer (score 0):

Keep your pages elements structure as private data and have the public elements to update them

```
var page = (function(){
    var private_data = {
    //json
    };

    return {
        workOnData : function(){//process the data}

    }
})()
```

This is good way you can keep your pages data safe and smooth.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use jQuery to do that if I were you o: then you could do something like...

```
$('div.updateThisClass').css('color','#fff')
```

Comment: I did (no offense intended) but for no other reason than I think you are *completlely* missing the point :)

Comment: not really, just change css to... whatever it is you want to be triggered and have an anon function to keep doing stuff with it? ;)